# Buck boost converter inductor rating

Tags: power, power-electronics, buck, buck-boost

I am designing a buck boost converter with a 12v output, and 50A current output.

The input range is 8v-14v from a supercapacitor. However based on the Texas Instrument buck boost design sheet [Basic Calculation of an Inverting Buck-Boost Power Stage](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva721a/slva721a.pdf) that the average inductor current formula is

[image]

[image]

The max duty cycle is 58 % which will make the average current of the inductor to be 120 A.

Do I need to find an inductor with rated current of 120A?

Comment: woah, 50 A ? Which kind of supercapacitor do you use to power this? Anyways, yeah, designing an inductor's peak current to be ca 2 times the output current doesn't seem far off, considering your least input voltage is 3/4 of the output voltage.

Comment: You need to start looking at multiphase converters to get 120 A.

Comment: Interleaved, multiphase converters approach is the way to go.

Comment: *Do I need to find an inductor with rated current of 120A?* Depends what current rating. Thermal, probably. Saturation, probably more, you need to allow for peak current. There are other configurations with lower inductor requirements, but they need more FETs. That inverting arrangement uses the smallest number of active devices possible.

Comment: could you explain how this 20A output is able to support by this single inductor?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-LVmZFrXhs&t=198s&ab_channel=Robojax